# VBA SetFocus on Keydown not working if checkbox true?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have the following form in excel. It is part of a simple inventory worksheet, and is used to update the status of items. It was functioning as intended, however when I tried to add in a checkbox to make the selected status persist (allowing me to only type in the serial rather than serial and status every time when working with a batch of items) I noticed that the focus after submitting cycles forward as if I pressed *tab* rather than being where I set it with `SetFocus`.

I'm presuming this is an oversight related to either the event cycle for KeyDown or nested If/Else logic, but I've had no luck actually diagnosing it. I've only recently started using VBA, and there are a lot of quirks I'm trying to understand.

```
Private Sub clear()
    Me.txtSerial = ""
    If cbPersist.Object.Value = False Then
        Me.cboxStatus = ""
        Me.cboxStatus.SetFocus
    Else
        Me.txtSerial.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub submit()
    Dim loc As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Full Inventory")
    Set loc = ws.Columns("B").Find(what:=Me.txtSerial.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not loc Is Nothing Then
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = loc.Row
        ws.Cells(loc.Row, 10).Value = Me.cboxStatus.Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Serial not found."
    End If
    clear
End Sub

Private Sub txtSerial_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
        submit
    ElseIf KeyCode = vbKeyEscape Then
        clear
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    cboxStatus.List = Array("Stock", "Shipped", "Research", "Sent Back", "Return")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest the following:

**Code snippet of UserForm module**

```
Private Sub txtSerial_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
  If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
    submit
    KeyCode = vbKeyPageDown     ' << modify Enter key value to prevent from tab hopping
  ElseIf KeyCode = vbKeyEscape Then
    clear
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems to work fantastically. Would you mind explaining why overriding the KeyCode prevents the tab hopping? My assumption is that after completing KeyDown the Enter key attempts to move forward in the TabIndex, overriding the SetFocus in submit?

Comment: Glad it works. Think your assumption to be true, thus with vbKeyPageDown your are on the safe side.